# Is it possible to drag uibmodal or to make the parent page not go dim?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

uibmodal makes the parent page go dim. Is it possible to stop that from happening?

Comment: use `backdrop` option per docs. As for draggable there are lots of draggable libraries around or use native html5 api yourself

Comment: Thanks, have you looked in ngPopup? I'm not sure if this is popular enough. Tried using it but doesn't really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved that by adding css:

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Do you know how to drag a modal or to resize it?

Comment: Read @charlietfl comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***backdrop: false***, per the docs:

```
backdrop (Type: boolean|string, Default: true) - 
   Controls presence of a backdrop. Allowed values: true (default), false (no backdrop), 'static' (disables modal closing by click on the backdrop).
```

[Docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)